# rename/refactor an udf parameter in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to rename it and that should reflect in all the dependency objects. Is there any built-in stored procedure to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nope.**

You can search `sys.sql_modules` system view for references to it in the `definition` field, but you still need to edit those objects manually.